# How to read my USIM with my PC

Tags: assembly, gsm

I'm trying to modify my USIM(with GSM 11.17 or ETSI TS 136)

I know there are some Hardwares called SIM Reader(http://www.sim-reader.com/).

But I have a 3G Phone with a USIM and its USB cable.

With all of these if I can accese a USIM then maybe

I don't need to pay extra cost to buy a Reader Machine.

In this case, I think some softwares(which can read only USIM information) will be needed.

I'm curious how most of programmers do.

name of softwares in use or another way to hacking USIM etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the AT commands from [3GPP TS 27.007](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/27007.htm), either programmatically or via Hyperterminal to get information from the SIM similar to what SIM Reader does.
Connect the phone the computer via USB and communicate via the modem port (you can find it in Windows Device Manager).

Answer (score 0):

Data in USIM is stored as files(EF) & can modified by proper verification only. All the Efs have access conditions & require authentication to modify. But yes you can read many files like IMSI, iccid etc but cannot modify these because only operator/card vendor is authorized. You can modify very few files like usim address book for example.
So by just having a tool to access usim it doesn't mean that you can modify also.
regarding hacking, i am not aware of any such tool/method for usim.